# Nao robot Error Loading a Local Module: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: shared-libraries, cross-compiling, nao-robot

i'm trying to create a local module in robot NAO in linux with the c++ sdk, as in this tutorial http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/cpp/tutos/create_module.html#cpp-create-module. I have compile and sent the library libmymodule.so to the robot, also i have add the path to the module in the autoload.ini file. But when i run the naoqi the module does not work.

Reading this http://agravier.com/2013/NAO-C++-tutorial-part-3-The-Apprentice-NAOmancer, and applying this command: less /var/log/naoqi/head-naoqi.log i get the following error: Could not load library: /home/nao/naoqi/libmymodule.so, Error was: /home/nao/naoqi/libmymodule.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64. The file libmymodule.so is of 64 bits, but also other librarys that are on the nao-sdk folder are of 64 bits, so i dont know what is the problem.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robot has a 32-bit i686 processor.
It looks like you have compiled the binary for your PC, not for the robot.

To compile for the robot, you will have to use the cross-toolchain. Since I could not find it on the official website, [here is a copy](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7EAustinVilla/software/linux64-cross-i686-aldebaran-linux-gnu-gcc-8.1.0.tar.gz) from a third-party.

You could also contact the support to request it. But you will need Linux to make it work.

Otherwise you might be able to do it with a [third-party cross-toolchain like `musl`](https://musl.cc/).

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I solved this problem some months ago. I uploaded a tutorial on YouTube about how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4cPDtk7-4A&t=933s&ab_channel=EmanuelMarquez

Comment: Please accept the answer, then ;)